# How can I filter out Java methods according to version?

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I need to generate a jar library in three different versions. Some methods of the classes are marked with annotations that specify the version when they were added. For example:

```
public class A {

  @SinceVersion(2)
  public int getTotal() {
    // do something...
  }

  @SinceVersion(5)
  public int getMax() {
    // do something...
  }  

  @SinceVersion(4)
  public int getAverage() {
    // do something...
  }  

}
```

Then:

- When I generate `my-library-2.jar`, only `getTotal()` should be included.
- When I generate `my-library-4.jar`, only `getTotal()` and `getAverage()` should be included.
- When I generate `my-library-5.jar` all three methods should be included.

This is a simplified example. The real problem spans 300 classes, 10 versions, with 6 subversions each.

Comment: Ideally, you'd create a multi-release JAR file with duplicate classes, some of which will have different methods depending on the version. See: https://blog.codefx.org/tools/multi-release-jars-multiple-java-versions/

Comment: @JacobG. That would be the solution of last resort. I have 60+ versions and growing. I would need to copy all classes 60 times. Considering I currently have 300 classes, that would generate a total of 18,000 clasess. I don't want to maintain 18,000 classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to post the solution I found in case is of help for someone else.

After researching for a week I finally found [Apache Commons BCEL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/). This library allows you to inspect and modify a class loaded in the JVM; once modified it can be written to the file system as a .class file.

A piece of code like this produces a new class file **without** some methods:

```
import org.apache.bcel.Repository;
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.AnnotationEntry;
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.JavaClass;
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.Method;
import org.apache.bcel.generic.ClassGen;

JavaClass clazz = Repository.lookupClass("test.House");
ClassGen cg = new ClassGen(clazz);
Method m = findMethod(clazz, "close");
AnnotationEntry ae = m.getAnnotationEntries(); // process annotations here...
cg.removeMethod(m); // remove the method you want to remove
JavaClass modifiedClazz = cg.getJavaClass();
modifiedClazz.dump("./gen/test/House.class"); // save to a new file
```

By walking the whole tree of classes (or a subpackage tree) it's possible to find all affected classes, process their methods, and remove them if the annotation values match some criteria.

Answer (score 1):

You may wanna look into implementing an annotation processor.

Annotation processors run during compile time and are used to create and/or manipulate code, and I use them to create boilerplate code, as well as code that's otherwise tedious to maintain manually, but has a clear structure.

Comment: This sheds light on it. I think I'll need to try it for real, but looks like it could work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use source control (git, etc.) to manage your releases?  when you tag a release with v2.0, then code up to that point will have only getTotal().  Then v4.0 comes a long, and the code up to that point will have getTotal() and getAverage(), and so on.

Each release can be managed and built independently, and produce the specific jar file for that specific release.

Your client will then include whichever version of the jar it needs.

Comment: Thanks, but the project already has source control. The problem is I need to generate depending on the client version... and those can be as many as 60.